# Apache Phoenix's behavior with limit

Tags: apache-phoenix

I would appreciate if someone could help with my question regarding pheonix's functionality.

Created a phoenix table and inserted 100,000 records(assume these are spread across different region servers).

Now, when I issue a select query with a limit n..something like this

```
select * from <phoenix_table_name> limit 1000;
```

What would be phoenix's behavior?

- Does it read the all the data(from all the region servers) on side server side, then apply limit to dataset and send the 1000 records to the client?

or

- Does it bring all the data set to the client and then apply the limit?

Answer (score 0):

Without any hurdles it has to work. It means it would fetch first 1000 records.

Comment: The question wasn't about if it would work. It was about how does it work I think.